# Oracle histogram - identify columns

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, database-performance

How to identify which all columns need histogram in a table? Is there any Oracle query to identify it? Or some manual steps ?

Answer (score 1):

Ask oracle to collect statistics using the default settings and it will collect histogram. The pre-requisite is that you must have run the workload (or at least parsed the queries) before collecting the stats.

Comment: To be more specific, I want to know which column needs histogram. I do not want to create it. Is it worth to check the column values (how many rows for distinct values)?
...
method_opt => 'FOR ALL COLUMNS SIZE 254', or DEFAULT* ---- to create the histogram forcefully or automatically* 
...
What do you mean by "you must have run the workload"? Please give some more details.

Comment: How are you still getting support for oracle 10g?

Comment: We are on 11g now.

Comment: By running the workload, I mean the queries have to have been parsed.